# Using Smooth Scroll inconjunction with Data Filter

Tags: php, html

I've set up a responsive image map that uses data-filter to filter through experiences depending on where has been clicked. However because the image is big (as desired) it looks as though the page isn't working when a region is being clicked. To fix this I want to add in a smooth scroll option that scrolls down to the part of the page that changes

Is there a way I can use smooth scroll to scroll down to the experiences as well as filtering them out?

```js
var MileniaIsotopeWrapper = (function($){
 'use strict';

 /**
  * Base configuration of the module.
  * @var {Object}
  */
 var _config = {
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  transitionDuration: 500,
  originLeft: getComputedStyle( document.body ).direction !== "rtl",
  masonry: {
   columnWidth: '.thg-grid-sizer'
  },
  activeFilterClass: 'thg-active'
 };

 /**
  * Initializes new IsotopeWrapper instances.
  * @param {jQuery} collection
  * @param {Object} config
  * @return {jQuery}
  */
 var isotope = function( collection, config ) {
  collection = collection && collection.length ? collection : $();
  if( !collection.length ) return collection;

  config = config && $.isPlainObject( config ) ? config : {};

  return collection.each(function(){
   var $container = $(this),
    containerConfig = $.extend( true, {}, _config, config, $container.data() );

   if($container.data('isotope-layout') == 'grid') {
    delete containerConfig['masonry'];
    containerConfig.layoutMode = 'fitRows';
   }

   if( !$container.data( 'IsotopeWrapper' ) ) {
    $container.data( 'IsotopeWrapper', new IsotopeWrapper( $container, containerConfig ) );
   }
  });
 };

 /**
  * Isotope wrapper.
  * @param {jQuery} container
  * @param {Object} config
  * @constructor
  */
 function IsotopeWrapper(container, config) {

  /**
   * Contains link to the current container.
   * @type {jQuery}
   * @public
   */
  this.container = container;

  /**
   * Contains configuration object.
   * @type {Object}
   * @public
   */
  this.config = config;


  this.init();
 };

 /**
  * Initialization of the current isotope container.
  * @return {undefined}
  */
 IsotopeWrapper.prototype.init = function() {

  /**
   * Contains link to the current object.
   * @private
   */
  var _self = this;

  this.container.isotope( this.config );

  this.container.jQueryImagesLoaded().progress( function() {
   _self.container.isotope( 'layout' );
   _self.container.trigger('milenia.isotopeReady');
  } );

  if( this.container.data('isotope-filter') ) this.initFilter();
 };

 /**
  * Reinitialization of the container layout.
  * @public
  * @return {undefined}
  */
 IsotopeWrapper.prototype.relayout = function() {
  this.container.isotope( 'layout' );
 };

 /**
  * Initialization of the filter of the isotope container.
  * @public
  */
 IsotopeWrapper.prototype.initFilter = function() {
  if( this.filter ) return;

  var _self = this;

  if( this.container.data('isotope-filter') ) {

   this.filter = $( this.container.data('isotope-filter') );

   if( !this.filter.length ) {
    this.filter = null;
    return;
   }

   this.filter.on('click.IsotopeWrapper', '[data-filter]', function(e){

    var $this = $(this);
    if( !$this.data('filter') ) return;

    $this
     .closest(_self.filter)
     .find('.' + _self.config.activeFilterClass)
     .removeClass(_self.config.activeFilterClass);

    $this.addClass(_self.config.activeFilterClass);

    _self.container.isotope({
     filter: $this.data('filter')
    });

    e.preventDefault();
   });

  }
 };

 return {
  init: isotope
 }

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<section class="thg-section pad-50" style="background-color: #301C3F">
    <div class="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <h1 class="white kaushan">Choose your dream holiday</h1>
    <br>
    <nav class="thg-filter-wrap">
    <ul id="portfolio-filter" class="thg-filter thg-list--unstyled">
<img src="images/world-big.png" alt="" width="1271" height="748"  usemap="#Map" class="mb-40"/>
<map name="Map">
<area shape="poly" coords="832,397,946,410,958,513,1026,572,992,667,725,642,766,523,832,400" href="#offers" data-filter=".thg-category-bars-lounge" target="offers">
<area shape="poly" coords="946,367,964,512,1040,572,1266,605,1265,348" href="#offers" data-filter=".thg-category-activities" id="click">
<area shape="poly" coords="14,55,11,506,437,424,394,85,16,55" href="#offers" data-filter=".thg-category-pools-beach" id="click">
<area shape="poly" coords="494,217,541,388,621,342,724,362,803,325,728,130,609,144,578,213" href="#offers" data-filter=".thg-category-restaurants" id="click">
                   <area shape="poly" coords="1117,195,872,171,839,390,945,397,940,363,1150,353,1213,349,1228,184,1119,196" href="#offers" data-filter=".thg-category-meetings-events">
</map>
<h4 class="white" style="text-transform: none;">Trending Destinations</h4>
<hr class="mt-0" style="border-color: #00bccc !important;">
<li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="thg-active white">All</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".thg-category-activities" class="white">South East Asia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".thg-category-bars-lounge" class="white">Indian Ocean</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".thg-category-meetings-events" class="white">Middle East</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".thg-category-pools-beach" class="white">North America</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".thg-category-restaurants" class="white">Europe</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</section>
     
    
     
<!--================ End of Filter ================-->
                  <div class="thg-section thg-section--py-medium thg-section--stretched-content-no-px pad-50" style="padding-top: 50px;" id="offers">
                   
                    <div class="thg-entities thg-entities--style-17">
                      <div data-isotope-layout="masonry" data-isotope-filter="#portfolio-filter" class="thg-grid thg-grid--isotope thg-grid--cols-4">
                        <div class="thg-grid-sizer"></div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-rooms">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-10.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-0" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-10.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
        <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-meetings-events">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-11.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-1" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-11.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-activities">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-12.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-2" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-12.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-restaurants">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-13.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-3" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-13.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-restaurants">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-14.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-4" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-14.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-spa-fitness">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-15.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-5" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-15.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                           <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-rooms">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-16.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-6" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-16.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-pools-beach thg-category-bars-lounge">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-17.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-7" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-17.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-video thg-category-activities">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-18.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-8" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-18.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="thg-grid-item thg-category-meetings-events">
                          <!--================ Entity ================-->
                          <article class="thg-entity thg-entity--with-thumb">
                            <div data-bg-image-src="images/project-image-19.jpg" class="thg-entity-media"><a href="#" aria-labelledby="portfolio-heading-9" class="thg-entity-link thg-ln--independent"><img src="images/project-image-19.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                            <br>
                           <h4 class="purple">Idylic Thailand City and Island Stay</h4>
         <p>Bangkok is a vibrant city that bursts with life at any time of the day. Then escape to the beaches of Koh Samui and Koh Toa which own Thailand's most picturesque beaches</p>
         
         <a href="" class="purple">Explore More</a>
                          </article>
                          <!--================ End of Entity ================-->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                  </div>
                 
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You are more than likely using a JavaScript library to perform the filtering. Please provide information on the library being used.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I've added the JS